# Best way to design class with enum dependency

Tags: java, oop, class, object, enums

What would be the best way to design this class.
Flag class is a simple enum

```
public enum Flag { ... };

public class Example {
  private final Set<Flag> flags;
  pubilc Example(Set<Flag> flags) {
    this.flags = flags;
  }

 public Set<Flag> getFlags() {
   return ImmutableSet.copyOf(flags);
 }

 public boolean isValid() {
   return flags.contains(Flag.VALID);
 }

 public boolean isRequired() { ... };
}
```

Some factory code to create the example object.

```
Set<Flag> flags = EnumSet.allOf(Flag.class);
Example ex = new Example(flags);
```

Which one of the following is a better practice:

Approach 1:
In the client code I would then check

```
if (ex.isValid()) { ... };
```

The flaw I see in this approach is if I add a new Flag, I would also have to create a new IsX method in Example class, which violates open close principle?

Approach 2:
or avoid all the isX method in the Example class and in the client just have this:

```
Set<Flag> set = ex.getFlags();
if (set.contains(Flag.VALID)) { ... }
```

The flaw in this is all the extra boilerplate code?

Comment: I'd avoid giving the `Example` class the responsibility of determining if it is valid or not. Can't you wrap those validations in a full fledged validator and encapsulate the validation logic there? Adding a flag won't affect any other class but the validator itself. Some code has to change after all and its better for it to be in a single place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not doing something like:

```
public boolean isFlagged(Flag flag) {
    return flags.contains(flag);
}
```

Then your if-s will look like:

```
if(ex.isFlagged(Flag.Valid))
```